# android checking condition on radio group

Tags: android, radio-button

I have two question regarding radio group..In my apps, there have a list of question. Each question have the answer either "Yes" or "No" in the form of radio group. I design my code like this.

```
private ArrayList<String> errorMessage = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
boolean pergiHaji = true;
```

and this is the code for sample question.

```
//Question 1
if(rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rbtnYS2)
{
    pergiHaji = pergiHaji && true;
}
else
{
    pergiHaji = false;
    errorMessage.add("\n 1) Anda mempunyai masalah mental");
}

//Question 2
if(rg3.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rbtnYS3)
{
    pergiHaji = pergiHaji && true;
}
else
{
    pergiHaji = false;
    errorMessage.add("\n 2)Anda masih belum baligh"); 
}

//Question 3
if(rg4.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rbtnYS4)
{
    pergiHaji = pergiHaji && true;
}
else
{
    pergiHaji = false;
    errorMessage.add("\n 3) Anda bukan dalam golongan orang-orang yang merdeka");
}

//Question 4
if(rg5.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rbtnYS5)
{
    pergiHaji = pergiHaji && true;                  
}

else
{
    pergiHaji = pergiHaji && true;
}
```

if the question is all correct, it will display like below. Else, it will display all the errorMessage.

```
if(pergiHaji == true)
{                       
    tv.setText("Tahniah, anda layak mengerjakan haji");
}
else
{
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SemakanActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, errorMessage);
    listV.setAdapter(adapter);
    listV.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

My questions are

**1)** How to check whether all the radio button is checked or not.? Means, user must answer all the questions before submit.

**2)** How to ignore other question for example, I need to answer question 1 only. Question 2 until 4 are not related to 1. So, no need to answer. But if i press submit button, it will display all the errorMessage. I don't want to display errorMessage for question 2 until 4.

Thats all. Sorry if my example is too long. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

on your first question, checking if a radiobutton has been checked is pretty simple:

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(buttonId);
if(radioButton.isChecked()){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How to check whether all the radio button is checked or not.? Means, user must answer all the questions before submit.

I assume you mean `RadioGroup` here and that you want at least one `RadioButton` from each group to be `checked`. You can put the `RadioGroup`s in an `ArrayList<RadioGroup>` then on clicking submit you can run a `for loop` to see if each one has a button checked. For example

```
for (int i=0; i<rgArray.size(); i++)
{
    if (rgArray.get(i).getCheckedRadioButtonId() == null)
    {
         // do something here like add to a different array to show error message that these aren't checked
    }
}
```

This of course assumes that you have them all unchecked when the `Activity` starts

> 2) How to ignore other question for example, I need to answer question 1 only. Question 2 until 4 are not related to 1. So, no need to answer. But if i press submit button, it will display all the errorMessage. I don't want to display errorMessage for question 2 until 4

What? Please clarify...I'm not sure exactly what you mean